# Is ◻((◻(P → ◻P)) ↔ (◻P v ◻~P)) derivable in S5?

Tags: modal-logic

Is ◻((◻(P → ◻P)) ↔ (◻P v ◻~P)) a theorem in S5?

If so, is it also a theorem in B or just S5?

Answer (score 1):

Yes (S5) and No (B).

Using completeness, it suffices to show that (◻(P → ◻P)) ↔ (◻P v ◻~P) is true in any model, any world. Choose an arbitrary model. Since everything is accessible from everywhere, there is no need to mention it anymore.

Pick a world w and assume the left side holds in w: If w ⊧ ~◻P, then there is a world v with v ⊧ ~P. If there is any world u with u ⊧ P, then by the assumption ◻(P → ◻P), u ⊧ P → ◻P, so u ⊧ ◻P which means that v ⊧ ~P, a contradiction. Thus there are no such worlds u, all worlds must satisfy ~P, thus w ⊧ ◻~P.

Now assume the right side. If w ⊧ ◻P, then ... Can you take it from here?

In B the direction (◻(P → ◻P)) → (◻P v ◻~P) is still derivable, a proof very similar to the above works. The converse is not true though. 
Here is a countermodel:

[image: Countermodel]

If you are in the left world, ◻P holds. If ◻(P → ◻P)
is supposed to hold, then P → ◻P should be true in the middle world, which it is not.

**Remark**:
This should be intuitive: The left side has a nesting of two, the right side a nesting  of one. With formulas of nesting n, you make possibly statements about worlds n steps away. In transitive models every accessible world is only one step away (that is what the *validity*, not truth, of 4 says). But B is not transitive, so you cannot expect to derive a formula of nesting two from a formula of nesting one (it can happen of course, but the information about the distant worlds must be trivial).